# mysql database field type for search query

Tags: mysql

I tried searching in different terms & got some answers too but they were not matching to my requirements. like [This Link](https://www.guru99.com/regular-expressions.html)

I am using a sql statement something like below to fetch matching results from MySQL table.

```
SELECT statements... WHERE keyword_title_field REGEXP 'abc|axy|91store';
```

My questions is:

- What data type (e.g. varchar, text etc) should i choose for **keyword_title_field** field in **MySQL table** to fetch results quickly without putting much load on table/server.
- My current data type is **Text** due to unknown character length supply by user. Is this best suited or should i change?

Though it's not mandatory but any reference reading along with answer would be great for my understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some things to consider:

1. When you use any field in conditions (like REGEXP, LIKE or even '=') it is importand that you put an INDEX on the field. This will make MySQL not search every record 1 by 1, but find it via its INDEX instead. So make sure to look into that -> https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-indexes.htm
2. The less characters allowed in your field, the smaller the INDEX is. You however have variable lengths to consider, so a TEXT is fine. If you know the maximum length and it's less than 256 characters, use a VARCHAR. Just make sure to index the field.
3. Note that REGEXP is relatively slow. LIKE '%term%' would be prefered, but that of course depends on your needs. If it's just 'abc' OR 'axy' OR '91store', you could consider this query: `SELECT statements... WHERE keyword_title_field IN ('abc', 'axy', '91store');`

Comment: Thanks @Tum for the answer. Though i later realized that i put up something else what was required but your answer helped me to catch my answer. :-)

Comment: Just for the information, i changed Text data type to Varchar & added simple index. This change has improved query efficiency by ~50 ms